# Embed Tableau with Authentication

Tags: tableau-api

I have a requirement to embed a tableau report into another web page. We are using the tableau JS:

http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/embed_code.htm

Question is: Is there an authentication option whereby our application (web page) can pass authentication credentials to Tableau so the user does not need to enter the credentials?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are probably looking for the Trusted Authentication, as described [here:](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth.htm)

> When you embed Tableau Server views into webpages, everyone who visits
>   the page must be a licensed user on Tableau Server. When users visit
>   the page they are prompted to sign in to Tableau Server before they
>   can see the view. If you already have a way of authenticating users on
>   the webpage or within your web application, you can avoid this prompt
>   and save your users from having to sign in twice by setting up trusted
>   authentication.

There is [also an example showing how to use it](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_concepts_authentication.htm):

> If you are working with Tableau Server, and if the server is
>   configured to use trusted authentication, specify the ticket in the
>   URL by first adding trusted after the server name, followed by the
>   ticket. For example:

```
var placeholderDiv = document.getElementById("tableauViz");
var url = "http://tabserver/trusted/Etdpsm_Ew6rJY-9kRrALjauU/views/workbookname/viewname";

var options = {
   hideTabs: true,
   width: "800px",
   height: "700px"
};

var viz = new tableau.Viz(placeholderDiv, url, options);
```

Comment: thanks! The instructions require changes to config files on the server. We are using Tableau's SaS (online.tableau.com) which does not allows us to access the file system. Is there a way to perform this task in this situation?

Comment: glad I could help! The second link above has the following: `Note: Trusted Authentication is not used with Tableau Online.`. Probably it is not available using Tableau Online. You could contact them to clarify this.

Comment: I'm also using Tableau Online and yet I keep getting a 403 error "Could not locate unexpired trusted ticket". I have copy and pasted code from their docs on how to build a jwt. My connected app is enabled and open to all domains as well...

Answer (score 3):

I know this is pretty old, but the above isn't the only answer.

**New Answer**: The new [v3 Embedding API from Tableau](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/embedding_api/en-us/index.html#introducing-the-embedding-api-v3) introduces a new HTML web component: `<tableau-viz>`. You can pass a JWT in the `<tableau-viz>` element's "token" property to auth an embedded view for a Tableau user without the user needing to be actively logged into Tableau.

**Old, but still valid, answer:**

If you're using Tableau Online, you have two options:

1. Make your viz public, then just use the embed URL like your sample code, or
2. If you want or need to protect your viz behind authentication without having users present credentials on each vizualization (which based on your question seems like your plan) you can set up SAML authentication in Tableau Online with an IdP/SSO provider like Okta, AD, Salesforce, etc. Check the below docs:

https://help.tableau.com/current/online/en-us/saml_config_site.htm

Once you've set up the Tableau Online SAML authentication, you will need to set up a Sign In/Authentication page for the IdP/SSO platform. Most platforms will have a sign-in page for your integration or you can set up your own. If you set up your own, there is usually a fair amount of code to add for authentication.

As long as the user is authenticated in the IdP/SSO platform with access to the Tableau Online SAML authentication, the Tableau Online viz should not ask the user to enter their credentials as they are also "signed in" to Tableau Online (via the IdP/SSO platform).

Comment: Embedding a Tableau report with the new Tableau Embedding API is very straightforward, as shown in this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-9ey3w1?file=index.html). I wonder if it was inspired by the [ngx-tableau](https://github.com/nfqsolutions/ngx-tableau) library (of which I am the main contributor)